# commutant of the corner of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $p$ is a projection in $M$. Does there exist relationship between the commutant $(pMp)'$ of $pMp$ and $pM'p$.

I know the fact that if $p\in M'$, we have $(pMp)'=pM'p.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N=M'$. Then $p\in N'$. So, by the fact you know,
$$
(pM'p)'=(pNp)'=pN'p=pMp.
$$
Taking commutant (and here you need to be careful when taking double commutants of degenerate things),
$$\tag1
pM'p+(1-p)B(H)(1-p)=(pMp)'. 
$$
If you want to consider $pMp\subset B(pH)$, then
$$
pM'p=(pMp)'.
$$

Comment: If $pMp\subseteq B(pH)$, how to conclue that $pM'p=(pMp)'$?

Comment: You just compress equation $(1)$ with $p$.